# Facing Local Minima Problem using SLSQP Optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize

I have objective function for Revenue which is in the form of e^(beta1*log(P1) + beta2*log(P2) +....beta250*log(P250)) where P1,P2... P250 are price of certain items and beta1,beta2,... beta250.are elasticity coefficients from model. I would like to maximize Revenue and currently using SLSQP provided constraints on prices, units and guest count. The problem I am facing is optimizer is getting stuck at local minima (It return same o/p when I relax bounds on price by 5% or 10% or even more). I tried using manually written gradient and using approx_fprime. In both the cases it is getting stuck at local. I could not go with global optimizers as they take lot of time and we are planning to deploy optimizer in real time so that store managers can use it. Can you suggest some algorithm which do not have local minima problem and should converge in less than 30 to 45 secs.

Thanks

Comment: Imho this already happens automatically if you don't provide a customized one. There might be differences in regards to some optimizers and what exactly is used (e.g. lbfgs might have some internal fortran code doing this; resulting in not using scipy's code), but in general you are trying to enforce numerical-diff when there is already numerical-diff being done. The question is: what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thank you Sascha. I have added my question above.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have the whole model, so bring limited to work with partial information, here are some remarks:

- The `max Exp(sum())` objective can be replaced by `max sum()` (as `exp()` is monotonic).
- For global optimization problems, I often use solvers like Baron, Couenne, and Antigone. The problem may be small enough to prove global optimality.
- You can also try a multi-start approach: use multiple different starting points. This will at least prevent some really bad solutions. Some solvers have this built-in (e.g. Knitro) but it is not very difficult to implement this with a simple loop.
- SLSQP is a local solver. In theory, you could use `basinhopping` + SLSQP but I am not sure this works correctly with constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice. If I understand correctly you are trying to optimize an objective function with 250 parameters using a local optimizer, SLSQP. Now, I don't really know how the landscape of your 250-dimensional objective function looks like, but if in any direction you have more than a valley then any local optimization algorithm will get stuck in a local minimum, unless you provide a starting point that is already very close to the global optimum.

This is a relatively enormous amount of parameters to optimize while seeking a global optimum. The only suggestions I have is to put in your gradients analytically, code your function and gradients in Cython or FORTRAN+f2py (although I am not sure how much of a gain you can get with that) and try either a global optimizer (see, for example, http://infinity77.net/global_optimization/multidimensional.html) or a multi-start SLSQP with different starting points.

Depending on the algorithm (and the machine you are using), 30 to 45 seconds may give you more than 100,000 function evaluations. Not huge for a problem this size: if the objective function landscape is complicated, the odds are unfortunately not with you.